# создание папки и файла android studio в apk

Tags: java, android

есть код

```
String FILE_NAME = "content.txt";
    String text = " Write :  Ok  " ;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {

        fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(text.getBytes());
       // Toast.makeText(this, "Файл сохранен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(fos!=null) fos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {

       // Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

все работает , создает файл и записывает.
вопрос : как поместить файл заранее записанный "content.txt" в apk или установщик приложения , чтобы потом можно было отредактировать в приложении ?

как поместить файл "content.txt" в внутреннее хранилище при установки приложения на телефон ?

Comment: Напрямую никак. Помещаете файл в `assets` и после установки (при первом запуске) оттуда его копируете уже куда надо.